# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str - get from json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I try to get all lattitudes and longtitudes from this json.

Code:

```
import urllib.parse
import requests

raw_json = 'http://live.ksmobile.net/live/getreplayvideos?userid='
print()

userid = 735890904669618176
#userid = input('UserID: ')

url = raw_json + urllib.parse.urlencode({'userid=': userid}) + '&page_size=1000'
print(url)

json_data = requests.get(url).json()
print()


for coordinates in json_data['data']['video_info']:
    print(coordinates['lat'], coordinates['lnt'])
    print()
```

Error:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /media/anon/3D0B8DD536C9574F/PythonProjects/getLocation/getCoordinates

http://live.ksmobile.net/live/getreplayvideos?userid=userid%3D=735890904669618176&page_size=1000

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/anon/3D0B8DD536C9574F/PythonProjects/getLocation/getCoordinates", line 17, in <module>
    for coordinates in json_data['data']['video_info']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Where do I go wrong?

In advance, thanks for your help and time.

I just post some of the json to show what it looks like.
The json looks like this:

```
{
  "status": "200",
  "msg": "",
  "data": {
    "time": "1499275646",
    "video_info": [
      {
        "vid": "14992026438883533757",
        "watchnumber": "38",
        "topicid": "0",
        "topic": "",
        "vtime": "1499202678",
        "title": "happy 4th of july",
        "userid": "735890904669618176",
        "online": "0",           
        "addr": "",
        "isaddr": "2",
        "lnt": "-80.1282576",
        "lat": "26.2810628",
        "area": "A_US",
        "countryCode": "US",
        "chatSystem": "1",
        },
```

Full json: https://pastebin.com/qJywTqa1

Comment: `json_data` must be a list of dicts. So first `[]` argument needs to be a slice or an integer...

Comment: …or it is a dict, but its components aren't. I believe this is the case.

Comment: Without some information on your data, it's hard to say. Please post your json data here.

Comment: ok, I just did :)

Comment: It looks like the code you posted and the code you ran aren't the same. The traceback points to a line `for coordinates in json_data['data']['video_i']:` What is `video_i`? It isn't there in your source.

Comment: Oh it's video_info. The error remains the same tho. It was a mistake i made just before posting it when I tried different things to make it work.

Comment: Full json added as a pastebin link if that's of any help.

Comment: If you've found an answer useful, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the tick mark next to it, so that others may find it useful in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL construction is incorrect. The URL you have built (as shown in the output of your script) is:

```
http://live.ksmobile.net/live/getreplayvideos?userid=userid%3D=735890904669618176&page_size=1000
```

Where you actually want this:

```
http://live.ksmobile.net/live/getreplayvideos?userid=735890904669618176&page_size=1000
```

So your were actually getting this JSON in your response:

```
{
  "status": "200",
  "msg": "",
  "data": []
}
```

Which is why you were seeing that error.

Here is the corrected script:

```
import urllib.parse
import requests

raw_json = 'http://live.ksmobile.net/live/getreplayvideos?'
print()

userid = 735890904669618176
#userid = input('UserID: ')

url = raw_json + urllib.parse.urlencode({'userid': userid}) + '&page_size=1000'
print(url)

json_data = requests.get(url).json()
print()


for coordinates in json_data['data']['video_info']:
    print(coordinates['lat'], coordinates['lnt'])
    print()
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!
Idk what this does: import json
with open('/tmp/data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(json_data, f, indent=2) but maybe I learn that one day. :)

Comment: @aquatic7 Whoops, sorry. That was debug code. I used it to save the actual response JSON to a file. You don't need that and I have removed it from the post.

Answer (score 0):

According to your posted json, you have problem in this statement-

`print(coordinates['lat'], coordinates['lnt'])`

Here `coordinates` is a list having only one item which is dictionary. So your statement should be-

`print(coordinates[0]['lat'], coordinates[0]['lnt'])`